# read an xls file using hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, xls

If I want to read the data from oracle table using hashmap then i can read it like this.........

```
String sql = "select * from DPY_VW_REP_DELIVERY_DTLS where weighed_date between ? and ?";
Object[] queryParams = new Object[] {dateFrom, dateTo};
List rsList = this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql, queryParams);
Iterator it = rsList.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    try
    {
        LinkedHashMap map = (LinkedHashMap) it.next();
        String[] strData = new String[14];
        strData[0] = map.get("WEIGHED_DATE_AS_CHAR").toString();
        strData[1] = map.get("WEIGHED_DAY_SLNO").toString();
        strData[2] = map.get("PARTY_NAME").toString();
        strData[3] = map.get("PARTY_ADDRESS1").toString();
        strData[4] = map.get("PARTY_ADDRESS2").toString();
        strData[5] = map.get("VEHICLE_NO").toString();
    }
}
```

but if I want to read an xls file containing same data using hashmap  how can i do it....

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by '*using hashmap*'. `JdbcTemplate.queryForList` returns results mapped to a List of HashMaps.

It maybe easier to read excel files using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or similar tools. Alternatively, if using a spreadsheet as a database, you can use `JDBC-ODBC` bridge. Then you can execute your `SQL` query. Here is an [example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0362.html) for this approach.

Comment: those are really nice examples which satisfy me for this question,
but can i extend the query in 2nd example                   `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery( "Select * from [Sheet1$]" );`
to
`ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery( "Select * from [Sheet1$] where value[rows][0] == 'SR_NO' " );`

Comment: @abhi depends on your file. try this: `Select * from [Sheet1$] where F1 = 'SR_NO'`. Excel returns F1, F2, etc as the column names when a header isn't present